# indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (103,) (103,10)

Tags: neural-network, ipython, softmax

my code is as next

```
AL = AL.T
print("AL = " + str(AL))
print("shape AL =" +str(AL.shape))

AL = [[ 0.00060828  0.00062134  0.00103428 ...,  0.00177817  0.00153976
   0.00220757]
 [ 0.00057424  0.00059807  0.00094907 ...,  0.00181722  0.00163071
   0.0017858 ]
 [ 0.00066254  0.00051859  0.00095111 ...,  0.00170046  0.00162012
   0.00231112]
 ..., 
 [ 0.00064599  0.00055204  0.00100892 ...,  0.0015652   0.00140016
   0.0020871 ]
 [ 0.0006461   0.00055202  0.00100921 ...,  0.00156518  0.00140028
   0.00208662]
 [ 0.00064608  0.00055209  0.00100905 ...,  0.00156585  0.00140004
   0.00208697]]

shape AL =(103, 10)
```

For Y I have:

```
Y =[[0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 ..., 
 [0 1 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]]

shape Y = (103, 10)

m=103
```

Then I calculate the log_likelihood as follow:

```
log_likelihood = -np.log(AL[range(m),(Y)])
```

I have as output error:

```
IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (103,) (103,10)
```

I don't understand because both dimensions are (103,10)?

103 is representing my examples and 10 is representing my classes.
Do I do something wrong by calculating the log_likelihood one way or another?

Comment: What does `m` represent? Naturally `range(m) = range(103)` has a shape of (103,) and cannot be broadcast with a two-dimensional (103,10) tensor.

Comment: maybe you need `-np.log(AL[range(m)],(Y))`

Comment: @JoshFriedlander m represents my amount of examples (so 103). I thought it must be just an index. So Y has a shape of (103,10). How do I get my log_likelihood to work then? I want to keep my dimension of Y (it is my one hot vector). And I want to overloop my examples so 103 in my case...

Comment: Just to be sure, you are trying to find the most likely Y label for each row, based on the probabilities in AL? If so, try `np.argsort`

Comment: What I try to calculate is the min cost per training example for the highest probability found in AL.

Comment: What I try to calculate is the min cost per training example for the highest probability found in AL. But it is in training mode, the correct label is known (Y), the one hot vector (see above)! So, what I think should happen is for eg training example 1 (m=1), the log_likelihood should be calculated from AL with index (1,5). 5 because for the first example the correct label is 5... And so on for all other trainingsexamples.

Comment: BTW if I use the command: print("m shape = " + str(m.shape)) then I have as output error: 'int' object has no attribute 'shape' So how is it possible then I have the output error above like: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (103,) (103,10)

Comment: @krishna if I use your code then I have TypeError: ufunc 'log' output (typecode 'd') could not be coerced to provided output parameter (typecode 'l') according to the casting rule ''same_kind''

Comment: @lise what are you trying to achieve? give some context, that'll help people to understand your code better and you'll definitely get help.

Comment: @Krishna coding a neural network with 10 classes ( digit 0 to 9)